# High voltage DC power line for batteries

Tags: power

I am planning to install a photovoltaic plant of 1000Wp on the roof that puts into 10×12V batteries in series to have 120V. This way can guarantee a low section of the cable, if I had a 12V power line I would have a big one.

I want to install DC plugs 12V and 5V to power as much stuff as I can.

To step down voltage 120V -> 12V I need a DC DC converter on each plug but thinking to something cheaper I am wondering if it is reasonable a voltage divider instead of DC DC step down converter.

What do you think of this solution?

Answer (score 5):

Terrible proposal - you harvest all that energy and waste it in heat using a potential divider. A potential divider on DC can only be achieved using resistors and these will fry if you try and take any sensible power from them.

You can use a SMPS wall-wart - they'll operate on DC - after all they convert the power AC to DC only to switch it at high frequencies through a transformer to a low voltage ac then rectify it. Give it a try but choose one that is capable of working down to 85Vac.

CAUTION - potential high voltages that could hurt a lot - be careful

Comment: ok I will have a try!

Comment: I would **NOT** assume that an arbitrary power supply will work on DC without reviewing the design.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've never seen an SMPS wall-wart that wouldn't BUT I can't discount that one may be AC coupled. If it is AC coupled then it won't work but thankfully it won't be unsafe